# A Regular expression to find second occurence in DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a string column in a Data Frame that i want to extract a rate from that is the last occurrence of backslash.

```
 After so many requests, this is Bretagne. She was the last surviving 9/11 search dog, and our second ever 14/10. RIP*
```

I want to get `14/10`

Comment: df[column].str.extract(\d+\/\d+.*?(\d+\/\d+))?

Comment: @politicalscientist It didn't work but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to get list of all your date in this sentence

```
import re
re.findall(r"\d+/\d+","After so many requests, this is Bretagne. She was the last surviving 9/11 search dog, and our second ever 14/10. RIP* ")
```

to get the second just select the second item in this list

Answer (score 0):

This regex works:

```
>>> s = "After so many requests, this is Bretagne. She was the last surviving 9/11 search dog, and our second ever 14/10. RIP*"
>>> re.findall("\d+/(?=[^/]*$)\d+", s)
['14/10']
```

Comment: @DODE No problem, also since my answer gives you the direct result with more concise regex, you should consider accepting this answer :)